# How to setup a Android simulator

Tags: android, emulation

How can I setup a android simulator in Ubuntu 15.10? Genymotion seems the best way, but is to expensive for me. I tried install the SDK simulator and ended up with some problems and couldn't get it to work. Is there any other step by step ways I can install a simulator? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu-make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) should have you up and running in no time... The command to do it is:

```
umake android
```

It should install the SDK, configure it, and install Android Studio.

Comment: I got it installed and everything, How can I open a app in it though? It doesn't look like a normal simulator. @Palantir